# VB.NET - Integer with multiple points value

Tags: vb.net, integer, decimal, points

I need to check if "4.1.1.1" (example) is greater than "4.1.4" (False in this case), how can I do this in VB.Net when there are multiple decimal points in the 'integer'?

Comment: it is *not* an integer.  It's a string structured as a Hierarchical Key.

Comment: How would I go about declaring a 'Hierarchical Key' so that I can check if it is greater or lower than another?

Comment: As an array (or list) of integers.  And the Split() function will do that for you.

Comment: Well,,... Split() will make an array of strings for you... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a vb expert. But maybe something like this:

**Test values**

```
dim str as string="4.1.1.1"
dim str2 as string="4.1.4"
```

**str larger then str2**

```
dim result as boolean=( _ 
from split in str.Split(".").Select(function(s,i) New With {s,i}) _ 
join split2 in str2.Split(".").Select(function(s,i) New With {s,i}) _ 
on split.i equals split2.i _ 
where cint(split.s)<cint(split2.s)
select 1).Any()
```

**str2 larger then str**

```
dim result as boolean=( _ 
from split in str.Split(".").Select(function(s,i) New With {s,i}) _ 
join split2 in str2.Split(".").Select(function(s,i) New With {s,i}) _ 
on split.i equals split2.i _ 
where cint(split.s)>cint(split2.s)
select 1).Any()
```